# How do I print the first letter and second letter and third.. of each string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I enter: 'I love stack overflow', how can I print first&second&third letter from this string.

The output to be like this:

'Ilso', 'otv', 'vae', 'ecr'...

If anyone can help me with this would be great! Thanks :D

Comment: You mean you want to print all first, second and third letters of each word, not of the whole string. Look into `str.split`, `str.join` and `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Use `str.split`, `str.join` and `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s = 'I love stack overflow'

result = [''.join(chars) for chars in zip_longest(*s.split(), fillvalue='')]

print(result)
# ['Ilso', 'otv', 'vae', 'ecr', 'kf', 'l', 'o', 'w']
```

---

### Explanation

`s.split()` splits the string into a `list` of words, seperated by space. `zip_longest` returns tuples of characters from all words, filling up the missing values (for short words) with the empty string `''`. `''.join()` concatenates (adds) the characters to a new string. The list comprehension loops over all the letter tuples, first letter, second, etc.

Comment: Wooo, thats a good way to do so. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'I love stack overflow'

words = string.split()

longest_word = len(max(words, key=len))

result = [

    ''.join([
        word[index]
        for word in words
        if len(word) > index
    ])
    for index in range(longest_word)
]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the solution

```
a='I love stack overflow'
l=a.split()
for i in range(len(max(l,key=len))):
    b=''
    for j in l:
        try:
            b=b+j[i]
        except Exception:
            pass
    print(b)
```

Comment: Never use bare `except:`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/51685

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have edited to the regular one now

Comment: If you mean to catch an `IndexError`, then catch it specifically. Also, I suspect you'd want to `break` instead of keep `pass`ing on more exceptions that'll inevitably occur past the last valid index?

Comment: The second loop actually iterates through the list of words in a string. So if I break instead of the pass then the loop will stop on the second character.